# how to count the number of records from an union operation in SQL?

Tags: sql, count, union

I am using following SQL query

```
SELECT count(column1) from table1 where CONDITION1
UNION
SELECT count(column1) from table1 where CONDITION2;
```

When I run the query it give two numbers in outcome. But I need a single number result where it will count the number of records from the above operation. I don't know how to write that query. Can anybody help me?

Comment: i.e. sum of first row and second row?

Comment: yea. but should be distinct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT count(column1) from table1 where CONDITION1 OR CONDITION2
```

Comment: This is most likely what he wanted, but strictly speaking it returns a different result than his query whenever (CONDITION1 AND CONDITION2) = TRUE

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you meant to have `table1` twice

```
SELECT
    SUM(TheCount)
FROM
    (
    SELECT count(column1) AS TheCount from table1 where CONDITION1
    UNION
    SELECT count(column1) from table1 where CONDITION2
    ) X;
```

or

```
    SELECT count(column1) AS TheCount
    from table1
    where (CONDITION1) OR (CONDITION2);
```